# Element does not react on jQuery event

Tags: jquery, validation, events

There is a question form validated by [Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It has a lot of fields with checkboxes and radiobuttons, and I want them to be checked after clicking a link with href="#checkbox-id".

```
...
<label class="answer-label" for="answer-2">
  <input id="option-2.1" class="answer" type="radio" name="answer-2" value="Yes"/>
  <a href="#option-2.1">Yes</a>
</label>
...
```

Javascript:

```
$("label.answer-label a").bind("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href").replace(".", "\\.");
  $(target).click();
} );
```

Here is validation plugin setup:

```
$("form#feedback")
    .validate({ submitHandler : function ( form ) {
                form.submit();
              },
              errorClass: "invalid",
              focusInvalid : false,
              debug : true,
              invalidHandler : function ( form, validator ) {
                  var destination = validator.errorList[0].element;

                  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop : $(destination).offset().top - 100 });
                  $(destination).focus();
              },
              highlight : function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                  if ( $(element).parents(".name-company") ) {
                      $(element)
                          .removeClass(validClass)
                          .addClass(errorClass);
                  }
                  // if ( $(element).parents(".question") ) {
                  $(element)
                      .parents(".question")
                      .removeClass(validClass)
                      .addClass(errorClass);
                  // }
              },
              unhighlight : function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                  if ( $(element).parents(".name-company") ) {
                      $(element)
                          .removeClass(errorClass)
                          .addClass(validClass);
                  }
                  // if ( $(element).parents(".question") ) {
                  $(element)
                      .parents(".question")
                      .removeClass(errorClass)
                      .addClass(validClass);
                  // }  
              },
              errorPlacement : function () {
                  return false;
              }
            });
```

**The problem is:** clicking on label checks the input element, but validation events fire only after the second click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround (or, probably, a correct way to trigger validation events)! The trick is to bind the "change" event on checkboxes and radio button, like this:

```
    $("#feedback input[type=radio], #feedback input[type=checkbox]" )
      .bind("change", function ( event ) {
              $("#feedback").validate().element($(this));
          } );
```

This binding must be set before any other "change" event binding, so that every "change" event will trigger the validation check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ID of the input if the anchor tag is always after the input. Try this:

```
$("label.answer-label a").bind("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().click().blur(); // or change
});
```

Additionally, .bind is depreciated in newer versions of jquery. If you are using jQuery 1.7+, use this:

```
$("label.answer-label a").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().click().blur(); // or change
});
```

And, if the elements are dynamic, you would need to use event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click", "label.answer-label a",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().click().blur(); // or change
});
```

To trigger validation, I added `.blur()` after the click. That may need to be changed to .change() depending on your validation code.

If you remove the `.click()`, does it still react the same? `.click()` really shouldn't cause the value of the radio to change.

Comment: Neither `.blur()` nor `.change()` worked. Links still behave as I described in initial post.

Comment: I found a way to achieve the desired behavior. After binding `.change` event (see my answer above) your code started to work.